# java user.home to return in local language

Tags: java, internationalization

When I run `System.getProperty("user.home")` on turkish windows 7, I get "C:\Users\aaaa" even though "Users" folder does not exist in my computer (I have the turkish translation of "users"). How can I get the correct user.home information?
Thank you

Comment: Wow. That's interesting. Possibly related to the following bug: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4787931

Comment: Another related link; http://www.cubiclemuses.com/cm/blog/archives/000189.html/

Comment: The bug mentioned by @aioobe suggests using System.getenv("USERPROFILE") in java 5, what version of java are you using?

Comment: specifically the version information is:

`C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)`

Comment: Ouch!!  That bug is nearly 7.5 years old, has 139 votes and is 7th on the top 25 bug list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even though "Users" folder does not
>   exist in my computer (I have the
>   turkish translation of "users").

That's not true. You have the "Users" folder. Windows just automatically translates it when displaying it. But you have to use "Users" for filesystem paths, which is what `user.home` returns. The localized name is only relevant for displaying it to the user. I'm not sure how to get it from Java code.

Frankly, I think the whole concept of displaying different folder names to the user than what is actually present in the filesystem is a bizarre perversion.

Answer (score 10):

Which version of Windows are you running? On Vista and above (2008, 2008R2, Windows7), the folder is called `Users` in the file system, irrespective of the current language. But Windows Explorer displays it in the language of the UI, "Benutzer" (German) in my case. You can check in a command window that the real name of this folder is `Users`.

Comment: Yup, that was bound to create some confusion. +1

Comment: you are right. I checked it programmatically with java C:\Users directory exists, but the translated folder name does not.